# Выделить жилы у листьев растений с помощью python

Tags: python, opencv

Нужна помощь. Я пытаюсь выделить структуру листа "Скелет" с помощью метода Кенни но результат не устраивает.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
path = r'C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\v.png'
img = cv.imread(path, 0)
edges = cv.Canny(img, 400, 300)
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Выделяется слишком много границ, а хочется получить только основную структуру как например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим вот эту

Comment: так вы же сами выставляете пороги. пробовали их менять?

Comment: выложите оригинальное изображение